# A cake shop has 5 different types of cake. I wish to buy a selection of 9 cakes. How many different choices do I have?

Tags: combinations

This is a question I am stuck on - it's worth four marks.

I assumed when I read the question the answer would be $45$, from $9 \cdot 5$.

However, is it $9\cdot 5!$, $5 \cdot 9!$ or even $(9\cdot 5)!$?

Comment: A cake shop has 5 different types of cake. You have 5 choices

Comment: Take a look at the source and look near the bottom at "combinations with repetition". It's very well explained there. https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: I'd say this is a stars and bars problem, so that the answer is $9+5-1 \choose 5$

Comment: Should be $9+5-1 \choose 5-1$ sorry

Comment: Can you solve this problem when there are just two different kinds of cakes? That will get you started on why your guesses are wrong, even if you don't know the methods the other answers refer to. It's often useful when faced with a problem like this to think about a simpler version.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem, for example

$$**|**||****|*$$

represents you buying two cakes of type 1, two cakes of type 2, zero cakes of type 3, four cakes of type 4 and one cake of type 5. This sort of abstract representation corresponds directly to a "choice" you are making in this problem, so you want to count the number of such choices.

The thing you are varying here are the bars, so you need to find the number of ways you can distribute the $4$ bars between $9$ stars, which is

$$N = {9+4\choose{4}} = {9+5-1\choose{5-1}}$$

This is because you can also think of it this way: you have $9+4 = 13$ objects:

$$ ooooooooooooo$$

and you have to pick $4$ which will become bars, the rest automatically becomes stars, so the number is clearly $13\choose 4$